# Remove borders from Bootstrap table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I've been trying to get rid of the lines in between the text. I've tried changing the borders to none, I've also tried text-decoration: none. Both doesn't work. Anyone know how to fix this?

```css
.table {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="table borderless">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Required and Nonrefundable Fee per Year</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Registration Fee: per child</td>
        <td>NT$50,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Student Accident Insurance Fee: per child</td>
        <td>NT$800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Parent Association Member Fee: per family</td>
        <td>NT$1,000</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: put your HTML code as well.

Comment: make your table tr border as none

Comment: try adding tr, th, td { border: none; } to your css

Comment: Yeh I'm pretty sure what @PenAndPapers suggested should work for you. Make sure you hard refresh your browser by the way in case it's a cache issue.

Answer (score 25):

I copied your code and tried to change and get what you wanted. Finally I was able to get an answer.

```
tr{
    border-top: hidden;
}
```

Tell me if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Will this works? I think border-top: none is the correct way.

Comment: Good to know! :)

Comment: Yes, it worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: worked for me as well!

Answer (score 4):

I think this will works..

```
.table>tbody>tr>td,
.table>tbody>tr>th {
  border-top: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

copy and past it on your Style sheet.

```
.table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>thead>tr>th {
padding: 8px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
vertical-align: top;
border-top: 1px solid rgba(221, 221, 221, 0)!important;
```

}

```
.table>thead>tr>th {
vertical-align: bottom;
border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(221, 221, 221, 0)!important;
```

}